# AndEngine: onAreaTouch triggers parent instead of child

Tags: android, touch, andengine

I am having trouble adding the OnAreaTouch to my sprites. I have a fullscreen Enitity (Recatngle) and i attach it to my parent scene. So the rectangle is the child right? So i attached it and overrided the OnAreaTouch method. Now it takes the touch event but triggers the touch event of the layer below. I mean i have a sprites below this and all are attached to the main scene and have their own touch methods. What is the problem here? How can I restrict the OnAreaTouch specifically to the layer/sprite only?

Please note: I am new to AndEngine and using GLES2 AnchorCenter branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement in two ways

1. When you going to child layer place boolean in parent touches as mention below and make it true when you shift to child layer

   ```
   @Override
       public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
               ITouchArea pTouchArea, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
               float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

           if(isChildLayer)
               return false;

           return true;
       }
   ```
2. If you want to pause the parent scene then make your layer as scene and place this code

   ```
    mEngine.getScene().setChildScene(childScene, false, true, true);
   ```